# Relacion entre columnas misma tabal en laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

Buenas a todos me gustaría saber como hago para relacionar 2 campos de columnas diferentes en laravel: Saber si el user_id pertenece al grupo_id:
[image: Tabla SQL]

y en la vista la condicion @if user is in group_id...
Como podria hacer todo esto aprecio cualquier ayuda :)
Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes utilizar los parámetros que te devuelva la query. Recomendaría la segunda opción por escalabilidad y tengas relaciones coherentes en tu base de datos.

```
@if $user->group_id == 1 o lo que sea
```

Normalmente se utilizarían dos modelos, uno User y otro UserGroup. Así creamos las relaciones entre modelos.

Primero en la migración del modelo UserGroup tienes que crear una foreign key:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
```

Después en tu modelo User, utilizas una relación.

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\UserGroup', 'user_id');
}
```

En el modelo UserGroup:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

Entonces ya puedes hacer en tu if:

```
@if $user->group == 1 o lo que sea
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta! Me sirvio :)